# How to setBackgroundColor of textview to a Paint instead of a Color?

Tags: java, android, colors, paint

ok i know i can set a textview's background color by `textview.setBackgroundColor(R.color.darkgrey)` or some other color but im in a slight different situation. I have an object with three properties a Name, Value and a Paint. I used this object to draw a pie graph and have made a bunch of textview as legends for the graph. All i want to do now is set the background color to the Paint i used for the graph. I set the Paint by using the setARGB method of android.graphics.Paint. I have gone through the android notes trying to find a converting method to change the Paint to a color but no luck.

Any ideas how to setBackgroundColor() for a textview using Paint?

Comment: Why not simply hold onto the ARGB value in your object, along with the name, value, and `Paint`?

Comment: yea the Paint ARGB value is held by the object but its just im getting a error "the method setBackgroundColor(int) in the type view is not applicable for the argument (Paint)" when i try to set the textview background to that paint

Comment: An ARGB value is an integer. Make your object hold a name, a value, a `Paint`, and an integer. Put the ARGB value in the integer. Use the integer with `setBackgroundColor()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to draw your text with canvas, you should do something like this:

```
public Bitmap myDrawText(Context context, String text, Typeface typeface, int  textSize, int width, int height) {
    Bitmap myBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,      Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas myCanvas = new Canvas(myBitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setSubpixelText(true);
    paint.setTypeface(typeface);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setTextSize(textSize);
    paint.setTextAlign(Align.CENTER);
    myCanvas.drawText(text, (width / 2), 40, paint);
    return myBitmap;
}
```

Now you have a bitmap of your text!

```
    ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.some_image);
    iv.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
```

Comment: Hi thank for the reply, im not actaully drawing the text, im drawn the graph and the text is just normal textviews in a listview. i've added a pic to show

Comment: Instead of text view use image view and with this function paint that text.

Comment: ok. but is there a simpler way to convert Paint to color? because if i have to use a image view i'll have to change the custom arrayadapter that ive made for the list..

Comment: creating a custom listview is so simple. try that.